# An adverb for when you're not exaggerating

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, antonyms

I want to say,

> Your situation is, *without exaggerating*, more severe than mine.

However, I want to replace "without exaggerating" with an *adverb*. Something like "undoubtedly".

Now I know the word "unexaggeratedly" has not been born yet, and that I can always use the same sentence I mentioned above, but I love using adverbs in this fashion. I'm curious to know if there's an antonym for the word "exaggeratedly".

## Update

I absolutely appreciate anyone taking time to answer and comment. I read the answers, and I accepted [@Boneist's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/494218/240907). But then I thought, that actually doesn't answer my question. I needed a single word (an adverb in this case) to state and **refute** *the idea of exaggeration.*

- *unarguably* [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unarguably):

  > it cannot be argued
- *unquestionably* [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unquestionably):

  > not questionable

Both of these **do not** refute *exaggeration*.

Same goes for other answers as well, namely, [the most up-voted answer so far by @Ubi hatt](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/494215/240907):

- *actually* [means](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/actually):

  > As the truth or facts of a situation; really.

  It has nothing to do with exaggeration!

Now, I don't want to invent words (i.e. *unexaggeratedly*, as suggested by [@Toothrot](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/494231/240907)). But maybe that's the only option?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92945/discussion-on-question-by-amir-a-shabani-an-adverb-for-when-youre-not-exaggera).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are couple of good suggestion already given to you. I will add my bit as well. I'd like to suggest the word **actually.**

**Actually** (*adverb*) [<sub>Oxford Dictionary</sub>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/actually)

> As the truth or facts of a situation; really.
>
> > That this situation continues and is actually getting worse is simply not good enough

So, your sentence can be rewritten as follows:

Your situation is ***actually*** more severe than mine.

**UPDATE:**

Etymologically ***[exaggeration](https://www.etymonline.com/word/exaggeration#etymonline_v_32779)*** means "*unreasonable or extravagant amplification*," 1560s, from Latin *exaggerationem*.

Further, *exaggeratedly* is an adverb of the noun *exaggeration*. According to Oxford dictionary ["*exaggeration*"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exaggeration) means "a statement that represents something as **better** or **worse** than it ***really*** is" i.e. a statement or an idea presented in a blowout proportion.

So, something representing opposite to *exaggerated* should be *[unexaggerated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unexaggerated)* which in-fact means: Not exaggerated, overblown, or unrealistic.

But, we know that the adverb unexaggeratedly (*which you are looking for*) does not exist.

So, in that case the idea representing something as "without exaggerating" or *not overblown* or *unrealistic* should be ***actual***. *Actual* according to Oxford dictionary means "Existing in fact; real". An adverb of the word *actual* is ***actually***. It means "truth or facts of a situation" i.e. something represented without exaggeration.

Comment: This usage is, IMO, incorrect.  The fact that 'actually' is a parenthetical means that it's a correction rather than the definition you supplied.  I can't make an edit which just removes the commas because edits need to be 6 characters.

Comment: Your update was very helpful, appreciate it.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani that's great. Please remove unwanted part from your update section. It may cause confusion to future readers.

Comment: Wouldn't that be more confusing? Because your update was a response to my update. And the act of **accepting** means that the problem I stated in my update has been solved.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani okay leave it!

Comment: It exists. It was coined in 1861, per the citation here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unexaggeratedly -- if you correct your error, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @Rich Good that you found **unexaggeratedly** on wikitionary. I found it on wikitionary much before you did. But, unfortunately almost all standard dictionaries: *M-W, Oxfords, Collins, Cambridge etc.* does not recognize **unexaggeratedly** as a word. Thus, making it a dubious word to use. Specially, if you are using such a word for academic purposes then, it is mandatory that you use the words which are part of standard dictionaries and easily recognized without them being caught by little red squiggly line.

Comment: The important point about dictionaries is that in order to be authoritative, they must contain citations -- here we have one, and so the collection it was found in really doesn't matter. Plus there are citations in Oxford for both *exaggeratedly* and  *unexaggerated* (oh hi little red squiggly line). The question doesn't state it's for academic purposes, so whether or not it's acceptable is really up to the person asking. Remove your error and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 18):

I would use

***[literally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally#h1)***

: in a way that uses the ordinary or primary meaning of a term or expression

// He took the remark literally.

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

"Don't take it literally. He is inclined to exaggerate."

According to [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literally):

In its standard use ***literally*** means
 ‘in a literal sense, as opposed to a non-literal or exaggerated sense’, as for example in 
"I told him I never wanted to see him again, but I didn't expect him to take it literally."

Comment: the trouble is that the word literally is literally overused for everything and no longer really has that meaning.

Comment: @WendyG Agreed, but I still think that *literally* is one of the best common words to use. It depends on the context.

Comment: It is pretty clear from context when *literally* is used literally and when it is used figuratively.

Comment: -1. This usage is too unclear. Strangely, the 2nd definition in your cited link says: " : in effect : virtually —**used in an exaggerated way to emphasize a statement or description that is not literally true or possible**"

Comment: @JamesRandom it literally isn't clear.

Answer (score 18):

Saying *"your situation is, [**undoubtedly**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/undoubtedly), more severe than mine"* would mean that there is absolutely no doubt that your friend's situation is more severe than yours. The meaning of this adverb is pretty straightforward. It simply means **without doubt** or **certainly**. It's a very common, everyday word.

Comment: This word is _unexaggeratedly_ more prevalent, and when thinking about the reader, it's _certainly_ more readable.

Answer (score 14):

I would use [**simply**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simply):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : without ambiguity : CLEARLY
>   **1 b** : without embellishment : PLAINLY
>   **1 c** : DIRECTLY, CANDIDLY
>   **2 a** : SOLELY, MERELY
>   // eats *simply* to keep alive
>   // *simply* cleaned it up and went to bed
>   — Garrison Keillor
>   **2 b** : REALLY, LITERALLY
>   // the concert was *simply* marvellous
>   —often used as an intensive
>   // *simply* crawling with geniuses
>   — F. Scott Fitzgerald

As you can see, there are a lot of synonyms for *simply*. Of those, I think that both **clearly** and **plainly** would also be good choices for your sentence.

Answer (score 14):

I would go with [Unarguably](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unarguably) (or *inarguably*, depending on your personal preference).

> Your situation is unarguably more severe than mine.

Or, perhaps, [Unquestionably](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unquestionably).

> Your situation is unquestionably more severe than mine.

I think I'd stick with unarguably, though; that sounds better to my ears.

Comment: I would say inarguably sounds more correct to my ears than unarguably, though Merriam-Webster lists both inarguable and unarguable as antonyms of arguable. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arguable)

Comment: @qdread Maybe it’s location specific? I’m in the UK, and “unarguably” is what I’m used to using.

Answer (score 13):

How about "Your situation is, **I shit you not**, more severe than mine"?

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20shit%20you%20not):

> The expression means I am being honest.
>
> When someone tells the truth about something usually unbelievable.

Comment: It's vulgar for sure, but sometimes vulgarity hammers a point home better than more polite euphemisms.

Comment: Hmm, maybe "unshittingly"

Comment: Or [I kid you not](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+kid+you+not) as a less vulgar alternative

Comment: people on this site definitely have a better sense of humor than people on Stack Overflow :)))) I appreciate that

Comment: Well done. You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Except you have replaced two words with four.

Answer (score 8):

I would use *[definitely](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/definitely)*. With this, there is no exaggeration or "unexageration" as you say. It just is.

> Your situation is definitely more severe than mine.

But if you are searching for a phrase, then I would go with *without a doubt*

> Your situation is, without a doubt, more severe than mine.

Since they are used in everyday conversation, I feel that these would be best fit for many situations.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use:

[**realistically**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/realistically)

> *2. In a way that is accurate and true to life.*

So, your sentence might be written as follows:

> *Your situation is, realistically, more severe than mine*.

I would think that, in your particular usage, it would draw some similarities between the other person's situation and yours, but wouldn't try to benchmark the severeness of it.

Answer (score 5):

I would use *certainly* or *indeed*.

> Your situation is *certainly* more severe than mine.
>
> Your situation is *indeed* more severe than mine.

But if adverbial phrases are okay with you, I'd opt for 'as it is'.

> Your situation, *as it is*, is more severe than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing the exact situation, I'd personally go with [**truly**](https://www.wordnik.com/words/truly).

It suggests both truth & accuracy, but it hasn't been misused as a few other suggestions have been, so less likely to be interpreted as condescending.

It also doesn't suggest extremes.  *Unarguably* and *Unquestionably* can be good choices for when the comparisons aren't close, but if they are, I'd go with **truly** instead.

Answer (score 4):

Seriously

> Your situation is, seriously, more severe than mine.

Also the informal word "legit", although listed in most dictionaries only as an adjective, is also used as an adverb. Being quite informal a dictionary probably should not be your guide on how it's commonly used, but Oxford Living Dictionaries and Wiktionary do list it as an adverb. In this case I guess it might be a flat adverb, like "safe" in "drive safe".

> legit
>   adverb
>   (slang) Honestly; truly; seriously.
>   He legit thinks he can pass the test on zero sleep.
>   That legit scared the hell out of me.
>   [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/legit)

...

> The word *legit* is used to mean 'literally' in utterances like 'I am legit going to fail this test'.
>   [Working with English Grammar: An Introduction (2018)](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=261eDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22am%20legit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0lqqf0tfhAhUSX30KHYtYDy4Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22am%20legit%22&f=false)

Comment: FWIW the proper form of the adverb "legit" is "legitimately".

Answer (score 3):

Consider *sincerely*, from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sincerely)

> in a sincere or truthful way : with truth, genuineness, or straightforwardness

"Your situation is more severe than mine, sincerely." Or "Your situation is, sincerely, more severe than mine.". With a special pause/emphasis around the word.

Edit: *Sincerely* isn't the best choice for that exact usage, but I wanted to mention it because I think it's a perfect word for most other situations, especially where you might otherwise sound sarcastic, or just like a general nice-ity but you want to make sure they know you're not just saying it to say it.  ("Oh, that dress sincerely looks great on you!" or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

**unexaggeratedly**

First,

> Your situation is, without exaggerating, more severe than mine.

means that your situation does not exaggerate.  You want to make
yourself the subject of the exaggerating:

> Your situation is, without *my* exaggerating, more severe than mine.

Now: the only adverb that may replace the without clause without changing
the meaning of the sentence is

**unexaggeratedly**

The notion that this is not "formal" or not quite all right so long as
it is not in a dictionary is misguided.  Nor is it right here to speak
of ''inventing words''.  The -ly ending is productive: it can generally
be attached to adjectives to produce adverbs.  The same is true of un-.
(You seem to recognize 'exaggeratedly').
Speaking of ''invention'' here is like saying that a sentence that
cannot be found by Google is an ''invented sentence'' and therefore not
proper English.

Comment: I think "without exaggerating" correctly implies that it's **I** who's trying not to exaggerate. However, if I were to explicitly mention that, shouldn't I say "without my **exaggeration**" or "without **me** exaggerating"? The "without my exaggerating" seems a bit odd to me! BTW, +1 for sticking to **unexaggeratedly** :)))) I am warming up to it. However it's not fun when there's a red line under it, indicating that it's not correct.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani, just turn off auto-correct!  for _my exaggerating,_ see Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage, under _illiteracies._

Comment: @Toothrot Sure, not every valid word is in the dictionary, but you might want to do something to prove that it's precedented and nominally understood in the exactly the way you suggest it's used rather than simply invented on the spot. Adding some illustrative quotations and an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unexaggeratedly%2Cunexaggeratingly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunexaggeratedly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cunexaggeratedly%3B%2Cc0) might help your answer considerably.

Answer (score 1):

I am late to answer, but this is my first answer :)

In the given situation, I would prefer the word **irrefutably.**

Your situation is **irrefutably** more severe than mine.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irrefutably

Comment: The word *irrefutably* means that it cannot be *disproved.* It does not state that I'm not exaggerating. Also, the link you provided differs from the word you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question properly, one must supply an adverb whose meaning is the *opposite* of 'exaggerate'.

To 'not exaggerate' is to speak **plainly**.

> Plainly : Without ornament or embellishment, simply; without luxury or excess, modestly, frugally.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144993?rskey=Kl9Nk0&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Your situation is, **plainly**, more severe than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see them working well/at all in your sentence as written (with "is" being modified),  [understatedly](https://books.google.com/books?id=IRtEkg28AsgC&pg=PA5&dq=understatedly&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0lqTrt9fhAhUpuVkKHXAuBGI4FBDoAQhPMAc#v=onepage&q=understatedly&f=false), [conservatively](https://books.google.com/books?id=MSoMOrSrlCEC&pg=PA229&dq=%22conservatively+describe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6i6y7xdfhAhVPtlkKHfViDWYQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22conservatively%20describe%22&f=false) or (to the extent that it's a word), [minimis/zingly](https://books.google.com/books?id=B_djAAAAMAAJ&q=minimisingly&dq=minimisingly&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWlZqUsdfhAhUIq1kKHT8jD14Q6AEINTAC) could arguably qualify as antonyms of "exaggeratedly" (i.e., as synonyms of "unexaggeratedly") and possibly work ok in the following rewrite:

Your situation can be described, [even] conservatively/understatedly/minimis/zingly, as being more severe than mine.

(linked examples above from *Pamphlet Architecture 29: Ambiguous spaces*; *Hemingway on War*; and *Ancient Indian Tradition & Mythology;: The Skanda-Purāṇa (pts. 1-15, 19)*, respectively, all via *Google Books*)

Answer (score 0):

I would naturally say:

> "your situation is ***obviously*** worse than mine".

- I think this language is much more realistic, especially in dialogue.
- It instantly placates and soothes the other person.
- This may or may not be technically accurate - e.g. perhaps their story **is** commonly regarded as false or exaggerated by others - **BUT I** am saying that to **ME** that they are definitely not exaggerating, and that they don't need to labour the point any more.
- The other answers here are great, but too formal, so none of them would sound genuine to me as dialogue... they feel passive aggressive. It's as though they are all followed by *"...**BUT** you're 'foo' so it won't be as much of a 'bar' for you (or insert other passive aggressive/diminishing/non-believing remark here)*
  whereas 'obvious' has no recourse, or qualifier. If something is obvious then the onus of misunderstanding is laid on the intelligence of the observer, not on the 'foo' of the 'victim'.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is, truthfully, worse than mine. That would convey the idea that there was no exaggeration. However it sounds wrong and I want to add the word "speaking" after the adverb.

Answer (score 0):

**[unostentatiously](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/unostentatiously)**

> (of an action) in a manner that is not done in an exaggerated way to
>   get people's attention.

([collinsdictionary.com](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/unostentatiously))